# how to uplaod image in django rest framework with heroku and aws s3 bucket storage

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am using heroku for my django rest framework project and i am using whitenoise storage but the problem with this is that after image uploading image it is disappear after some time

i want permanently image storage with aws s3 bucket help me with that

`models.py`

```
class UploadImage(models.Model):
    img_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)
```

what changes i have to make to use and store the images in aws s3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

`requirements.txt`

```
boto3==1.17.8
django-storages==1.11.1
```

or you can download using

```
pip install boto3
pip install django-storages
```

`settings.py`

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'YOUR_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

apply this changes and you will good to go